# TFS 2017 - work item Pre-Save event?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2013 through custom extensions we were able to do field validation just before a work item is saved. This model supported a number of events including pre-save, field-change etc.

In TFS 2017 the extensions seem to be supporting only *onFieldChanged, onLoaded, onUnloaded, onSaved, onReset* and *onRefreshed* events. So we're unable to intervene right before a user saves the work item with new values, revert them back and prevent the item from saving & going into the database & firing our work item tracking web services with these (as per business rules) invalid values.

Is there any way to accomplish this in TFS 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen onFieldChanged event, it will be fired immediately when a field be changed.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the only way to go about it. Since we have rules that include multiple fields and onFieldChanged fires for each field separately, I'm keeping these dirty fields and their values in a variable and compare them with the original ones (which I load up in another variable on onLoaded event).